# CKEditor Default File Path

Tags: php, javascript, file, ckeditor, fckeditor

Using CKEditor (combined with KCFinder for file upload), when I use the browse button and retrieve my file I get the path:

```
"/demo/cms/uploads/images/image.jpg"
```

Which is the path to the image, however if I then move the file around within the editor, the automatically path changes to:

```
"uploads/images/image.jpg"
```

Which won't work from where the content is really being pulled. Ideally I would like both paths to be "uploads/images/" but if there is a way to modify either one that will at least make it consistent that I can overwrite the path after the content is saved.

Is there a way to modify either of the paths? I haven't been able to find the value in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to use php and a regex to just strip out any path after the content is saved.